# "GDALGetActualBlockSize" error in QGIS while loading any GDAL/OGR related functions

Tags: qgis, error, gdalogr

I'm getting an error in QGIS 2.18.10 in openSuse Leap 42.2 which I have could not solve so far. When launching the program the following error message arises: "***Unable to load GdalTools plugin. The required "osgeo [python-gdal]" module is missing. Install it and try again***". After that message I get another one about the "Processing" plugin as follows:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 

ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALGetActualBlockSize 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 308, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 28, in 
    from processing.tools.dataobjects import *          # NOQA
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/dataobjects.py", line 37, in 
    from processing.algs.gdal.GdalUtils import GdalUtils
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/GdalUtils.py", line 32, in 
    from osgeo import gdal
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in 
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALGetActualBlockSize

Python version: 2.7.13 (default, Mar 22 2017, 12:31:17) [GCC] 
QGIS version: 2.18.10 Las Palmas, exported 

Python Path:
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/XXXX/.qgis2/python
/home/XXXX/.qgis2/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python27.zip
/usr/lib64/python2.7
/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2
/home/XXXX/.qgis2//python
```

Same happens with any GDAL-related plugin like  Semi-Automatic Classification:

[image]

The ***python-gdal*** package has been installed in the system since long ago. I'm not fully sure but I think the problem started after installing an additional instance of GDAL 2.1.3 from the sources (make, make install...) because it was the only accepted version by Geonode (installed in a python virtual environment). What makes me suspicious about this option is that the "About" section shows that QGIS is running against version 2.1.3 of GDAL/OGR (see picture below) but the only approach I've had with that version was the previously mentioned Geonode installation and currently there is no trace of it in my system (or at least I can't detect it).

[image]

I've tried everything I know but nothing works so far, like uninstalling and cleaning every trace of GDAL libraries (both 2.2.1 and 2.1.3 versions), reinstalling python, qgis, grass and all the GIS-software, reinstalling GDAL and the python bindings either from Yast or pip (both are version 2.2.1), changing vendor for QGIS and all GDAL dependencies either to Science or Geo repositories, performing several distro upgrades, deleting QGIS configuration folders and files, etc., but the problem remains.

Comment: After read your last paragraph (it was a lot of work), I recommend my own solution. I always have, at least, two **GNU/Linux** partitions in my hard disk. My first one is Debian stable (practically, it doesn't fail) and any other for testing (normally Ubuntu). I left to use rpm based distributions (Fedora 3), as openSuSE (I used it too), 12 years ago. They have many problems.

Answer (score 1):

had a similar experience.

Replaced qgis by the qgis ltr (Essen) version, changed all packages gdal, qgis, grass to those of the GEO repository.

qgis starts fine, without any complaint.